# the meaning of python3.x syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascals-triangle

I want to make a pascal triangle from python script. and this is my syntax that I get from [web.programminghub.io](http://web.programminghub.io/#/program/Python)

```
size = int(input("Enter the size of the triangle: ")) 
tri=[]

#creates a pascal triangle of size n
def pascal(n):
   """Prints out n rows of Pascal's triangle.
   It returns False for failure and True for success."""
   row = [1]
   k = [0]
   for x in range(max(n,0)):
      tri.append(row)
      row=[l+r for l,r in zip(row+k,k+row)]
   return n>=1


#prints the pascal triangle with correct spacing to 
#represent a triangle
def print_pascals_triangle(triangle):
    largest_element = triangle[-1][len(triangle[-1]) // 2]
    element_width = len(str(largest_element))
    def format_row(row):
        return ' '.join([str(element).center(element_width) 
for element in row])
    triangle_width = len(format_row(triangle[-1]))
    for row in triangle:
        print(format_row(row).center(triangle_width)) 
pascal(size)

print_pascals_triangle(tri)
```

the problem is, no explanation for every single of line from this script code. so can someone explain every line of this syntax meaning.

Comment: How about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36911593/264442

Comment: the results isn't like what i want. i want to make a perfect triangle shape for the output. this script is work, but i just don't understand what the meaning about every single line from this syntax code.

Comment: If you really want an explanation for **every** line of code, you'd better read a book first. If that's not true, specify which syntax you don't understand.

Comment: if like that, i  just want to now how about this script work. just the outline of this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function `pascal` generates a pascal's triangle stored in `tri`. The `print_pascals_triangle` prints the triangle symmetrically.

```
Enter the size of the triangle: 3
  1  
 1 1 
1 2 1
```

`pascal` generates `[[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]`.

`print_pascals_triangle` prints each row centered at a fixed width (`triangle_width`).

Comment: okay. thanks i get the outline explanation about this syntax.

Comment: once more. what is `tri=[]` is it a list, or something else ?

Comment: @SufferProgrammer `[]` is the syntax for an _empty_ list. You should visit [a tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python) on Python online for answers to questions like these, though.

Comment: Ok got it already. Thanks for the advice